# JavaScript/jQuery remove double quote from inline background URL Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom

Why is Firefox adding double quote to background url?

So I have something like this:

```
<div id="image" style="background-image:url(http://domain.com/images/img.jpg)"></div>
```

Now I want to replace image using jQuery on click event:

```
$("#replace").on('click', function() {
        $("#image").css({'background-image': 'url(http://domain.com/images/img2.jpg)'});
});
```

Everything works fine, but in Firebug, I can see double quotes:

```
url("http://domain.com/images/img2.jpg")
```

and this messes up my HTML, when saving and reloading.

I have tried to remove quotes using

```
$("#image").css({'background-image': ('url(http://domain.com/images/img2.jpg)').replace(/\"/g, "")});
```

but it does not work.

Is there a way to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

There is an typo in your HTML:

```
<div id="image style="background-image:url(http://domain.com/images/img.jpg)"></div>
```

It should be like:

```
<div id="image" <------- close this id attribute here
```

```js
$(function() {

 $("#btn").on('click', function(e) {
   $("#img-block").css("background-image", "url('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg')");
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-block" style="background-image: url('http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-23/data1/images/hohenschwangau532864.jpg');">
  Hello World!
</div>

<button id="btn">
  Replace
</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have fixed the typo, but that still does not change  the fact.

Comment: Yes, it works first time, but try now to view background image like this https://jsbin.com/ducopubapi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: See this, I've edited it, its working - https://jsbin.com/varibaliyi/1/edit?html,js,output use single quotes inside `background-image` tag

Comment: That's the point, even if I use single quotes, firefox is converting them to double quotes when content is saved

Comment: So whats the problem its causing